# AmazonSES DKIM signature not inserted with SendRawEmail

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, dkim

I've been using SES to send emails via the normal [SendEmail API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendEmail.html) command, and the DKIM signature has been working fine.

Now I want to send an attachment, so I started using [SendRawEmail API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendRawEmail.html) and the DKIM signture is not being inserted into the mail headers. This causes GMail to display the ugly **via amazonses.com** warning:

[image: gmail via warning]

I verified this by looking at the mail source with gmail's `Show Original`.

I found this same question on [Amazon's forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=428907). But it doesn't actually answer the question. It does say that once DKIM is enabled, it *should work* for both `SendEmail` and `SendRawEmail`.

So why isn't AmazonSES inserting the DKIM header for the raw email API?

(I'm actually using the ruby SDK, so it's `send_email` and `send_raw_email`, but it shouldn't matter.)

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had DKIM setup and enabled in the AWS SES console for my Domains. This domain-level DKIM had worked fine for `SendEmail`.

However, I had to enable DKIM for each sending email address under **Email Addresses** to enable DKIM on `SendRawEmail`.

[image]

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: weird - any idea why? it's funny cos I'm getting the opposite problem (according to mail-tester.com my message is signed twice)

Comment: I am using the SendRawEmail command, and I had only set up DKIM signature for my Domain .. (don't know how this information can help though). Also, maybe this can shed some light: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429881/aws-ses-from-nodejs-not-dkim-signed?rq=1