# AWS SES from NodeJS not DKIM signed?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am using nodemailer to send emails using SES

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const sesTransport = require('nodemailer-ses-transport')

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(sesTransport({
  accessKeyId: '...',
  secretAccessKey: '...',
  region: 'us-east-1'
}))
```

When I try to send test emails from AWS SES Dashboard, it works. But when I send via code, it goes into spam. I've already followed the steps to "enable easy DKIM" http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/easy-dkim.html. When I check the verification status of DKIM on AWS Dashboard, its verified. Do I need to explicitly sign emails when sending via code? In the example from https://nodemailer.com/dkim/, I need a private key. Which private key isit? Where do I get it? Also what values do I put into domainName and keySelector?

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    dkim: {
        domainName: 'example.com',
        keySelector: '2017',
        privateKey: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBg...'
    }
});
```

Comment: *Do I need to explicitly sign emails when sending via code?* Definitely not.  Have you inspected and compared the headers (in your email client) between the two email messages?  Landing in the spam folder can be for any number of reasons, unrelated to DKIM.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot How do I compare headers? Do you mean the view details of sender? I notice emails sent via code is missing signed by field.  Looks like the library nodemailer didnt sign it correctly, what I did was used AWS SDK directly and called `setIdentityDkimEnabled`, It works now

Comment: I am referring to comparing the headers in the messages you received.  For example, in GMail on a desktop browser, this is called "Show Original."

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, ok so theres a difference. Emails sent by nodemailer that is marked as spam is listed like `SPF: NEUTRAL with IP X.X.X.X` emails sent by AWS SDK directly is shown like: `SPF: PASS with IP X.X.X.X`,  `DKIM: PASS with domain X ` seems like nodemailer did not correctly sign my emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I can close this. It appears nodemailer didnt correctly sign emails using DKIM. Using AWS SDK directly and calling `setIdentityDkimEnabled` to enable DKIM fixes things.