# AWS SES SendRawEmail with via amazonses.com warning

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ses, dkim

Hi I'm sending raw emails with attachemnts from Amazon AWS SES using raw format. To prepare the message I'm using the library github.com/domodwyer/mailyak and the following code. The problemn is that I'm receiving the "via amazonses.com" warning on GMail. When I send the email using SendEmail method I didn't get this warning. My domain and email has the DKIM signature. I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883840/amazonses-dkim-signature-not-inserted-with-sendrawemail) from a similar issue, but also without solution.

The [mail-tester website](https://www.mail-tester.com) says that my message is has two DKIM signatures, one from my domain and other from amazonses.com

```
mail := mailyak.New("", nil)
mail.To(destinatario)
mail.From(remetente)
mail.FromName(remetenteNome)
mail.Subject(titulo)

if err := templateConteudo.ExecuteTemplate(mail.HTML(), "conteudo", emailData{Parametros: *parametros}); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return
}

if anexos != nil {
    for _, anexo := range anexos {
        mail.Attach(anexo.Nome, *anexo.Arquivo)
    }
}

buffer, err := mail.MimeBuf()
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return
}
dados, err := ioutil.ReadAll(buffer)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return
}

dadosSES := &ses.SendRawEmailInput{
    RawMessage: &ses.RawMessage{
        Data: dados,
    },
}

if _, err := sesCTX.SendRawEmail(dadosSES); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return
}
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/462664/126632

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton I found a comment at the link "If your 'from' description contains certain special characters it can fail even with everything set up correctly" I removed the special characters and worked. I'll work on a solution and post latter. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/462664/remove-via-from-emails-sent-to-gmail-from-amazon-ses) when the from descrition has special characters it fails to DKIM authentication. So I just mime encoded it using the following code.

```
mail.FromName(mime.QEncoding.Encode("UTF-8", remetenteNome))
```